# How to apply javascript to element created with append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append, element

I have a form that appears by append(). The form contains input that need to be adjusted with with js (autocomplete function).
Here is it:

```
function addForm() {    
<!-- function code here-->
...
html += '  <table class="form">';
html += '    <tr>';
html += '      <td>Entry product</td>';
html += '      <td><input type="text" name="product" value="" /></td>';
html += '    </tr>';
html += '    <tr>';
html += '    <td>&nbsp;</td>';
html += '    <td><div id="featured-product" class="scrollbox">';
html += '    </div>';
html += '    <input type="hidden" name="featured_product" value="" /></td>';
html += '    </tr>';
html += '  </table>';

$('#form').append(html);

}


$('input[name=\'product\']').autocomplete({
<!-- function code here-->
}
```

But autocomplete function doesn't work in this way. As I understand it is because of append(html) doesn't store the html to DOM. It works fine with usual html form, but i can't go this way. I need to create forms as described. So the questions are:
How can i apply js to element that are not in DOM?
 Or how can I execute this elemnt to DOM with js?
Maybe I need to use smth another like append()?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code:

```
$('input[name=\'product\']').autocomplete({
 <!-- function code here-->
});
```

after the code that appends the html. The problem is that when this bind is attempted the DOM does not contain these elements

You could also use the `.on` functionality to apply this:

```
$('input[name=\'product\']').on("autocomplete",function(){
 <!-- function code here-->
});
```